# How to use USB device in Android Lower version like Android 2.2?

Tags: android, usb, libusb

I am working with Magtek Magnetic Card Reader and connected that MCR with android device by USB. When i am using API 12 and onwards it is working fine but when i changed the API version to 8 it crashed and show the below result in Log cat:

```
   04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.hardware.usb.UsbManager
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.magtek.mobile.android.libDynamag.MagTeklibDynamag.openDevice(MagTeklibDynamag.java:98)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.magtek.mobile.android.MagTekDemo.Dynamag.MagTekDemo.onResume(MagTekDemo.java:119)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    04-12 11:39:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**So can we make the Android 2.2 USB enable and use the USB devices ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't.  The API you want to use didn't exist in 2.2.  This isn't the case where they changed the API, this is a feature they added that didn't previously exist.  And given that its hardware related, its not a matter of writing code to emulate it.  You're just going to have to live with API 12+

Answer (score 4):

I want to share that **we can use the USB device in lower version as well by just converting the USB HID devices into the keyboard type.** The input from the USB HID device treated like entered from a Keyboard. I have to use a Magtek MSR to swipe CC and want to get the CC info. But the device don't support the USB connection because of lower version.

Then i just changed the USB HID to keyboard type and now everything is fine. But for this that device can be changeable. So this is the way by which i am using the USB device into my application.